# If I created a task on a user called "A" and I want it to be executed on user "B", how do I do it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler, multiple-users

I'm looking for help with "Task Scheduler" Windows 10

I don't know how to do it but basically, I have two users, "A" has admin rights and "B" does not.

I also saved the .bat file on the Local Disk and gave permissions for "B": "Read" & "Read and execute" only as I don't want user "B" to be able to delete the .bat file ruining the script.

I want to create a task where it runs the "shutdown .bat file" at 5 PM which basically just shuts the computer down. How do I do that by Task scheduler?

Further and detailed explanation:
I want to create a task on task scheduler on the user "A", "A" has admin rights. I want it executed on "B", "B" doesn't have admin rights.
The task would do the following:
Daily at 5 PM, execute the following .bat file:

```
@echo off
shutdown /s /f /t /p 0
```

This .bat file is stored on Local Disk (E:). "B" only has "Read", "Read and Execute" permissions for the .bat file, so I cannot delete it through "B"

I was asking for a step-by-step on what to press on Task Scheduler and how to create the task exactly so I'd achieve the following:

```
 1. At 5 PM everyday, a shutdown .bat file would run on user "B" shutting down the device. 
 2. If you send a solution and it works even on "A" at 5 PM, sure, I just want B to shutdown once the clock reaches 5 PM.
 3. I want the task to run automatically through task scheduler, The task will be created on "A".
```

Why am I doing this?
I want to have myself like a certain time where I can spend time on PC, and it'd end on 5 PM

my .bat file just in case I wrote it wrong:

```
@echo off
shutdown /s /f /t /p 0
```

Comment: What's the problem in running a scheduled task as admin? The permissions on the file cannot stop an administrator.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean? I simply don't want "B" to have admin permissions because I don't want "B" to have permissions that could tamper with some programs I have going on.

Comment: I don't understand either. You, as you're admin, can create any scheduled task that you like.

Comment: Yea, What I'm saying is:

I want to create the task on "A" and have it executed on "B".
I tried to do it but it didn't work.
Here's the old script I was using:
@echo off
:W
if %time%==17:00:00.00 goto :X
goto :W
:X
shutdown.exe /s /f /t 20 /c

I tried this and it didn't work.
So instead I created a Task where it'd run the .bat file in the original post at 5 PM daily. I feel like this won't work again so I was asking for a step by step on what to press in Task Scheduler.

Comment: Still unclear: Does the task run automatically at 5PM, or does B manually need to run it at any time?

Comment: I want the task to run automatically through task scheduler, The task will be created on "A".

Comment: Then just do it this way. B is not concerned and doesn't need to have any permission on the batch file, even if he's logged in at 5 PM when that task runs. Note that B will lose any work that he started before 5 PM - this is a bit violent.

Comment: Yeah I have a digital clock next to me and I save once I hit 4:55 PM. I'm sorry but "Then just do it this way", What way? I create a task where:
Daily at 5 PM, the "shutdown .bat" will execute?

Well, I got a couple of questions:
1. If I created it on "A", will it work on "B"?
2. How do I create it exactly?? Do I need to check extra boxes so It can work across users? What do I do exactly, that's the point of the post, step-by-step guide on what to do.

Comment: It doesn't "work on B" - it executes in a system session. The logon session doesn't matter.

Comment: I'll try it and get back here if it's stuck. Welp, waiting until 5:00 pm tomorrow.